# Regular Expression dot in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I'm new in this field, and try to use `prxmatch` and `rxmatch` to match some strings.

The pattern is `a.`, which matches a string with more than 2 characters and `a` isn't the last one.

I run `prxmatch('/a./', 'a')` and `rxmatch('/a./', 'a')`, the result should be 0. But the system returns me 1.

So how can I get 0 in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a MCVE for this, you do get no match.

```
data test;
  x='a';
  rc=prxmatch('~a.~',x);
  put x= rc=;
run;
```

However, if `x` is not length 1, it will match!

```
data test;
  length x $5;
  x='a';
  rc=prxmatch('~a.~',x);
  put x= rc=;
run;
```

Why?

Because in SAS, strings are not `varchar`, they are `char`.  They have spaces padding the rest of the string out to its full length.  So you would need to do either

```
data test;
  length x $5;
  x='a';
  rc=prxmatch('~a[^ ]~',x);
  put x= rc=;
run;
```

or, better,

```
data test;
  length x $5;
  x='a';
  rc=prxmatch('~a.~',trim(x));
  put x= rc=;
run;
```

(Note, I use `~` for my regex delimiter - you're free to use slash, or any other character, for that, it makes no difference.)

Comment: Note: I would use `prx` in all cases; `rx` are not really supported any more as far as I understand.

Comment: @itzy Given it was made at the same time the other user deleted his answer, I assume that was the source.  If you didn't see it before you can't see it now (as it was deleted).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works nicely. And I feel sorry for the downvote.